# How to reuse puppeteer browser?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Instead of constantly relaunching the browser, is it possible to keep it open and use it in a function like this:

```js
async function render_html(url, browser) {
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    let html = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('*').outerHTML);
    console.log(html);
}

const browser = create_browser();
render_html('https://example.com', browser);
```

I found that it takes quite a long time to constantly open and close browsers, so if I only had one browser open to which I could open and close tabs/pages it would be a significant speed increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a browser instance, export it and use it in your different modules. Check this https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2444#issuecomment-384698480